# angular production compilation: function call is not supported in decorates but PublicClientApplication was called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

after enabling azure AD auth in my SPA app using MSAL. everything works perfectly on dev env but while using ng build --prod i get error *"error during template compile of 'AppModule' function calls are not supported in decorators but 'PublicClientApplication' was called."*
app.module.ts as following

```
imports..

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    ..,
    MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication(
      {
        auth: {
          clientId: environment.clientId,
          authority: environment.authority,
          redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
          postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.postLogoutRedirectUri

        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "localStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, //declared const
        },
      }),
      {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['User.ReadWrite']
      }
      },
      {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/', ['User.read']]
      ])
    }),
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: []

})
export class AppModule { }
```

I did some search and tried some solutions but none worked..

running ng build --prod didn't compile successfully